# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll fakes fail during build

Tags: msbuild, microsoft-fakes

I have this simple test project in vs 2013 I reference the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client in my library so added a Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client.12.0.0.0.Fakes in the test project, using right click add fakes assembly.

Locally everything works fine but when i run the project trough the build server using the default template I get Fakes: code : assembly XXX\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll failed to load properly.

The non fake dll's are included in a solution folder.

Any other assembly added by fakes working perfectly fine but as soon as I fake the Microsoft.Teamfoundation. my build breaks.

Using VS2013 with TFS 2012 update 2.

Comment: Any reason why you need to fake the reference instead of providing them from GAC on build server? Installing TeamExplorer should do the job.

Comment: Which version of VS is installed on your build machine? You need to install VS2013 if you have generated the fakes dlls using the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. The problem is because TFS and Visual Studio versions are not the same. I installed **`VS 2013`** to the server where TFS Build Server installed.

Then renamed `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes` folder and copied 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Fakes` folder into `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes`. This will solve your problem I guess.